# How do I extend the Zend Navigation Menu View Helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-navigation

I need to change the output of `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu`.  I've found the two functions that I'll need to modify, and I know how to make the changes I need.  What I don't know is how to make the Navigation object use my view helper instead of the Zend one.

Code snippet representing my class extension:

```
// file /library/My/View/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php
class My_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
{
    protected function _renderDeepestMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container,
                                          $ulClass,
                                          $indent,
                                          $minDepth,
                                          $maxDepth)
    {
        // modified code here
    }

    protected function _renderMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container,
                                   $ulClass,
                                   $indent,
                                   $minDepth,
                                   $maxDepth,
                                   $onlyActive)
    {
        // modified code here
    }
}
```

---

**Edits to Clarify**

I want to change the class of the `<li>` elements and remove the `EOL` and indentation.  There are no options to do that with the menu view script, which is why I'll have to extend it.

Initializing the navigation object in my Bootstrap:

```
$navTable = new Default_Model_Site_DbTable_Navigation();
$view = $this->getResource('view');
$view->navigation(new Zend_Navigation($navTable->getNavigation()));
```

Rendering the menu in my layout:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

---

**Solution**

I got it working by renaming things as follows, but I am not clear on why I can't overload/overwrite the `_Menu` class and `menu()` function.

1. Change the class name to `My_View_Helper_Navigation_MyMenu`
2. Add the `myMenu` function to the the class (`return parent::menu($container);`)
3. Call `echo $this->navigation()->myMenu();` in the layout

Class wireframe:

```
// file /library/My/View/Helper/Navigation/MyMenu.php
class My_View_Helper_Navigation_MyMenu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
{
    public function myMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null)
    {
        return parent::menu($container);
    }

    protected function _renderDeepestMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container,
                                          $ulClass,
                                          $indent,
                                          $minDepth,
                                          $maxDepth)
    {
        // modified code here
    }

    protected function _renderMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container,
                                   $ulClass,
                                   $indent,
                                   $minDepth,
                                   $maxDepth,
                                   $onlyActive)
    {
        // modified code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $view->addHelperPath(
      APPLICATION_ROOT . '/library/MyApp/View/Helper/Navigation',
      'MyApp_View_Helper_'
      );


echo $this->navigation()->myMenu(); // name of your class
```

From: [Getting Zend_Navigation menu to work with jQuery's Fisheye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243697/getting-zend-navigation-menu-to-work-with-jquerys-fisheye/1816494#1816494)

**EDIT**

Sorry I've not seen your solution, it is exactly what I've posted.

But why this is not a trully extension of menu class?

Comment: I don't understand why I can't re-use the `menu()` function and `..._Menu` class name like I do in other situations in the Zend Framework.  I have to use a different name.

Comment: I'm going to accept your solution as the answer, but I wouldn't mind if you explained why I have to use a different name when extending a view helper.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is due Zend_View_Helper_Navigation->__call() / findHelper() method which look for the helper first in the Zend library. So, to reuse the menu method you can call parent::menu(...).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might need an answer I found a better way and probably the intended way.

The only thing you have to do is to create your own custom view helper that extends 'Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract' and set default proxy for navigation view helper to your own.

E.g.

```
class Admin_View_Helper_NavigationMenu extends
                                     Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract {

    public function render(\Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null) {
        return "Hello world!!";
    }

}
```

and

```
$this->view->navigation()->setDefaultProxy("navigationMenu");
```

(I am changing default proxy in menu controller action, as it is added to action stack)

Having done that, it will be possible to use this in the view

```
<?= $this->navigation()->render(); ?>
```

*Note: You still have to rename the view helper class, but that's how view helpers work in Zend (Names are not supposed to collide).*

Comment: I tried to update to Zend Framework 1.12, and my navigation broke. I haven't had the time to revisit it, but maybe your solution will allow me to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**did you edit your post?** It seems like my answer is totally irrelevant to your question now?

---

If you say what you need to change it will be easier. At the moment your question is a little confusing.

I've assumed you want to edit the view AFTER you have **already** created your navigation. If you are able to do it **before** you create it, then its even easier. This bit below is a little confusing because you would normally change the options before hand.

```
// Get the helper navigation
$navigation = $viewRenderer->
                       view->
                       getHelper( 'navigation' )
                      ->menu()
                      ->renderMenu(
                    $YOUR_NAVIGATION_OBJECT,                                
                    array(  'minDepth' => null,
                        'maxDepth' => null,
                        'onlyActiveBranch' => false,
                        'renderParents'    => false,
                        // More options here


                    )                           

);
```

**excuse the indentation, it was really hard to get it lined nearly**

Notice that I used $YOUR_NAVIGATION_OBJECT above. You only use that if you use more than one Navigation on your page. Otherwise, you jus use Render() instead of RenderMenu().

Comment: I edited my post to address your concern with my question being confusing.  I had already narrowed down what I needed to change.  My original question still stands: "How do I extend the Zend Navigation Menu View Helper?"

Comment: I see. Okay. I will take a look, but I don't think I know the answer to this one.