# How do I set id prefixes used by Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_XXX

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

When I render a `Zend_Nagivation` instance in my view, by default the anchor tags have id's assigned with the prefix of the view helper, followed by a dash, and then the page's id.

Examples of Page 1's anchor id (all using the same `Zend_Nagivation` instance):

- `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu` = "menu-1"
- `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Breadcrumbs` = "breadcrumbs-1"
- `My_View_Helper_Navigation_MyMenu` = "mymenu-1"

This is perfect for most cases, but I'd like to set that prefix manually, and I can't find a way to do it.

---

**Solution**

Specifying the prefix can be accomplished by adding the following code, and then calling `setIdPrefix()` when rendering:

```
class My_View_Helper_Navigation_MyMenu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
{
    protected $_idPrefix = null;

    /**
     * Set the id prefix to use for _normalizeId()
     *
     * @param string $prefix
     * @return My_View_Helper_Navigation_MyMenu
     */
    public function setIdPrefix($prefix)
    {
        if (is_string($prefix)) {
            $this->_idPrefix = $prefix;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Use the id prefix specified or proxy to the parent
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _normalizeId($value)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_idPrefix)) {
            return parent::_normalizeId($value);
        } else {
            return $this->_idPrefix . '-' . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the navigation configured? From ini? Classes?

Comment: The `Zend_Navigation` instances, I currently have four, two are built from the database and two are from xml files.  This behavior occurs for all of them, regardless of the data source.

Comment: You know you can call your helper "Menu" instead of "MyMenu" in which case the plugin loader will load yours in place of the ZF one

Comment: @Phil - Thanks! I remember having naming trouble when I originally wrote the helper. I may have mistook one issue for another. Here's the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364695/how-do-i-extend-the-zend-navigation-menu-view-helper

Comment: Ah, forgot about the navigation helper proxy system. Overloading this would require more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract::_normalizeId()` for which I see no other solution than to create your own custom version of each navigation view helper you require.

Comment: I see that now Phil, thanks! It's using `get_class()` and then using the last part of the class name (underscore separated) and lower-cased to make the prefix.

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution, so I'm accepting it.  Thanks Phil!