# Zend_Navigation extending Menu class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

### Issue

I really need to extend Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu for my custom behaviour of its methods.
I use modules if it's important for you to know.

### Some solutions

- [How do I extend the Zend Navigation Menu View Helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364695/how-do-i-extend-the-zend-navigation-menu-view-helper)
- http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=5594
- http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2011/05/extending-navigation-view-helpers-zend-framework.html

### My problem

I've implemented all the solutions, their combinations and it still ends in failure... Guys, I am waiting for ANY hints.

**Edit:** The problem is that nothing happens. The standard helper is used (which works fine).

### My code

My *Bootstrap.php* file:

```
protected function _initNavigation() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->addHelperPath('/../library/Application/View/Helper/Navigation', 'Application_View_Helper_');     
    $view->navigation($this->doGetNavigation());
}
```

My `Application_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu` class (*ROOT/library/Application/View/Helper/Navigation*):

```
class Application_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
{
    public function menu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null)
    {
        echo 'Application_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu::menu(...)';
        return parent::menu($container);
    }
}
```

My `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getHelperPaths())` calling on view:

```
array (size=3)
    'Zend_View_Helper_' =>
array (size=1)
    0 => string 'Zend/View/Helper/' (length=17)
    'Application_View_Helper_' =>
array (size=1)
    0 => string '/../library/Application/View/Helper/Navigation/' (length=47)
    'Fleet_View_Helper_' =>
array (size=1)
    0 => string 'C:/repos/statistics/trunk/application/modules/fleet/views\helpers/' (length=70)
```

My script view:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

Comment: I've posted en edit. Have a look at 'The problem' paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Have in application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath.Test_View_Helper_ = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.view.helperPath.Test_View_Helper_Navigation = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/Navigation"
```

then in application/views/helpers/Navigation.php

```
class Test_View_Helper_Navigation extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation
{
    public function navigation(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null)
    {
         $this->view->getHelper ('Menu');
         $this->_helper ['menu'] = new Test_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu();
     return parent::navigation($container);
    }
}
```

in application/views/helpers/Navigation/Menu.php

```
class Test_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
{
    public function render(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null)
    {
        return 'It is I.';
    }
}
```