# zend framework 1.12 navigation from database

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, content-management-system

I am creating a CMS using zendframework 1.12, I am looking for a idea solution for creating website navigation using a controller and model(database) similar to this but this is not working with zend 1.12 [Click here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=znA1LgQSxsoC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=cms%20zend%20menu%20pro&source=bl&ots=f6Ghj4H0H5&sig=H3uf55FrRQ143VBTi9OWCFqKQa8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O98OVMbiA8qTuATt7IC4DA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA)

another solution I have found using xml which I do not need like this : https://coderwall.com/p/i7gosa

I also do not need it to be done with actionstack which is an over killing I have seen it several places.

Please suggest!

Comment: **Any suggestions please....**

Comment: Can this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364695/how-do-i-extend-the-zend-navigation-menu-view-helper ?