# Zend Navigation - display uri

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, routes

Here's a quick one.

In my `navigation.xml` I have this type of structure.

```
    <faq>
        <label>FAQ</label>
        <uri>/frequently-asked-questions</uri>
        <controller>faq</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </faq>
```

When using the view helper `$this->navigation()->menu()` is there a way to display the uri as the link, instead of the normal link that is generated through the controller/action structure?

for example I don't want the helper to render `<a href="/faq">FAQ</a>` like it normally would, I want it to render `<a href="/frequently-asked-questions">FAQ</a>`. (the uri's tie in with my Routes)

Thanks for any help, I'm a little bit stuck on this one.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up your own custom view partial like [this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243697/getting-zend-navigation-menu-to-work-with-jquerys-fisheye/1255289#1255289).  This might be the only way.  I'm not 100% sure, though, as `Zend_Navivation` is one of the few classes that I *don't* utilize in the Zend Framework.  Regardless, he does give a very thorough explanation on how to set all that up. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Zend_Navigation reference you should be fine by simply ommiting the controller-action part:

```
<faq>
        <label>FAQ</label> part
        <uri>/frequently-asked-questions</uri>
</faq>
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html